Teams tab authentication error "app resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match"
I am trying to get the access token in a teams app. but i always end up with this error "app resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match"
after creating the Entra ID app then using it in the teams developer platform then opening the app in teamstoolkit in debugger chrome, I tried to fetch the access token in the teams app, but i always get this error "app resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match"
I tried changing the manifest > webApplicationInfo > resouce :  between this
"api://localhost:53000/{AAD App client id}"
and this "api://{domain where teams is deployed}/{AAD App client id}"
but still getting the same error
src="https://res.cdn.office.net/teams-js/2.24.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"

microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
    successCallback: function (result) {
    
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById("token").innerText = "User token: " + result;
        },
    failureCallback: function (error) {
        // Handle error here
        console.log(error);
        document.getElementById("token").innerText = "error: " + error;
    },
    resources: ["https://graph.microsoft.com"],
});

In the manifest i have the following
"validDomains": [
    "localhost:53000"
],
"webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "{AAD App client id}",
    "resource": "api://localhost:53000/{AAD App client id}"
},


you can't use localhost for this, you need to use a tunneling tool, such as NGrok. Microsoft used to recommend NGrok specifically (see here for instance), as it was one of the first to market in this space and very easy to get up and running - today there are other options, such as Cloudflare Tunnels and Microsoft themselves even have a solution in Dev Tunnels. Essentially, this will give you a clean, httpS-secured, proper web domain you can use for local development.
